# mysql_query() with simple query segfault

Tags: c++, libmysql

I have this super simple code :

```
#include <winsock.h>
#include <mysql.h>

int main() {
    MYSQL mysql;
    mysql_init(&mysql);
    mysql_options(&mysql, MYSQL_READ_DEFAULT_GROUP, "option");
    if (mysql_real_connect(&mysql, "localhost", "root", "pass", "data", 0, NULL, 0)) {
        mysql_query(&mysql, "SELECT * FROM versions");
        mysql_close(&mysql);
    }

    else {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When debugging, I get a segmentation fault on line 9 (`mysql_query`).

An idea ?

Comment: Need stacktrace to find what is wrong. The code itself looks good to me. Try with a debugger

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This code works :

```
#include <winsock.h>
#include <mysql.h>

int main() {
    MYSQL* mysql = new MYSQL;
    mysql_init(mysql);
    if (mysql_real_connect(mysql, "localhost", "root", "pass", "data", 0, NULL, 0)) {
        mysql_query(mysql, "SELECT * FROM versions");
        mysql_close(mysql);
    }

    else {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

- Use a pointer for the `MYSQL`object
- <strike>Put the return of `mysql_init(mysql)` into `mysql` itself</strike> => Memory leaks
- Don't use `mysql_options`

Comment: MYSQL* mysql = new MYSQL;
    mysql = mysql_init(mysql); memory leak